# mysql: upsert row and json field

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `user_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `settings` json NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IDX_5471ee230b9746dfb775d6c354` (`user_id`)
)
```

I want to make a query that upserts `user_id` and `settings` (which is `JSON`).

I currently have this query, it upsers `user_id` as expected but the problem is that it overwrites the json `settings`.

```
REPLACE INTO foo(user_id, settings)   
VALUES (
    '3',JSON_SET(
            settings,
            "$.topLevelField", 
                JSON_OBJECT('nestedField1', true, 
                            'nestedField2', "01-01-2020")
        )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's REPLACE is basically a DELETE followed by an INSERT. It can only replace values with the values you specify in your VALUES clause. The VALUES clause can't use the previous values stored in the row.

You might be able to use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

```
insert into foo values ('3', JSON_SET('{}', '$.topLevelField', 
  JSON_OBJECT('nestedField1', true, 'nestedField2', '01-01-2020')))
on duplicate key update settings = JSON_SET(settings, '$.topLevelField', 
  JSON_OBJECT('nestedField1', true, 'nestedField2', '01-01-2020'));
```

This does take into account the previous value of `settings` in the on duplicate clause.

I used `'{}'` as a dummy value of `settings` in the first line just so I can make the JSON_SET() work similarly in both clauses.